# Not able to load tdl deaful project

Tags: tally

I am setting tally developer 9.after selecting preference i am not able to load default project of tdl in developer 9.can any one help me with this?

Files I have
Tally erp 9
Tally developer 9

Answer (score 2):

I found the same issue but I solved it. Tally Developer 9 software uninstalled and reinstall than solve and show all defaults TDL files.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

Select the check box *Load* in the *Tools > Preferences > Compiler/Execution Options*.